# How to escape-html in JSP before saving to database?

Tags: java, database, jsp, escaping

I am learning JSP and Java at the moment and wrote a (very) simple guestbook to get started with JSP. But i want to ensure that noone can use CSS, so i need to strip the HTML code before saving it to my mySQL database. I already searched here and found the "

```
  PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test VALUES (ID, ?, ?)");

  pStmt.setString(1, request.getParameter("sender"));
  pStmt.setString(2, request.getParameter("text"));
  pStmt.executeUpdate();
```

So what would be the proper way to do this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: have a look at [org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml(java.lang.String)).

More detailed answer: Escaping HTML is the job of the presentation code, not the database code. What if for some reason, you want to display you data at some point in a non-web environment, such as a classic GUI? You will have to unescape the whole thing, otherwise it will display total garbage.

Just save the data as it is and make sure you escape *everything* you get from the user *right before* you display it (ok, maybe not numbers stored as numbers, but you get the idea).

If you're using AJAX, you can take this even further and only escape your strings in JavaScript (or use innerText).

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for. Also, i will try to implement the escaping in the frontend, not the db.

Answer (score 4):

The usual practice is the other way around. We save whatever is in the `textarea`, and use `escapeXML` attribute of a `<c:out>` tag when showing it. This way everything CSS, HTML tags all will be treated as simple text.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use JSTL function: fn:escapeXml().

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
 ...   
 <input type="hidden" name="htmlCode" value="${fn:escapeXml(htmlCode)}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the HTML for security purposes, e.g. to prevent things like Cross Site Scripting attacks (XSS).

Search for Cross site scripting on Google/Stack Overflow for more details.

There will be several open source Servet Filters which will do this for you.

e.g. see [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/gmurray71/archive/2006/09/preventing_cros.html) for an explanation

Comment: You mean something like this ? http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project

Sounds great, and i dont loose the feature that users can use things like "<b>" and "<i>"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JSTL core library.

c:out has escapeXml on as default.

Examples:

```
<c:out value="${tp.title}" />

<c:out value="${product.listPrice}" escapeXml="false" /> //if you want turn off
```

This approach let you do escaping in presentation layer as other people recommended.