# How can I allow WYSIWYG editors and disable XSS attacks using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3

I have a enterprise level application where logged in users are authorized to post articles to page using a WYSIWYG editor. (You can consider this application as a website builder.)

Everything works fine, but the problems are;

1. WYSIWYG editor posts a HTML containing article, also some localised string characters which Laravel doesn't like, so Laravel's `alpha_num` check can't pass. (Therefore we don't use it on validation checks.)
2. We need to allow characters like `<`, `"`, `>` because they may want to do some basic styling using WYSIWYG editor, so `htmlspecialchars()` is not an option while echoing/sanitizing values, because harmful things like `<br>`'s break.
3. Users are able to post things like, `<script type="text/javascript>alert('Hello');</script>` or `</div></div></div><div style="width: 100%, height: 100% z-index: 999999">` It is a huge security risk, I know, but we can't really sanitize/escape anything. Users will still be able to write `<s<!---->cript>` and pass the check.

So, in short, we can't rely some built-in Laravel and PHP functions. We can't disable WYSIWYG editor also, because it is used often in majority of areas in spoken application.

What is the best way to avoid this?

I'm thinking about creating a custom rule on top of `alpha_num` on Laravel, which would be called as something like `alpha_num_localised_characters_plus_allowed_html_tags` and add that rule to any input containing WYSIWYG editor.

Is this a good way? Is there any better alternative? How do you deal with such issues yourself?

Note: Please note we already developed a huge sized application, we'll rely on quickest and most maintainable solution.

Comment: I want to make a little addition. We currently pass any input not being validated by Laravel (e.g email|alpha|alpha_dash|custom_validations) to be validated by HTMLPurifier::purify(). Let me know if there is a quicker way!

Comment: I wouldn't "validate" using htmlpurifier - rather use this just to make sure the input is "safe". The only validation I would do with laravel is "required" if the field is required. - see my answer below for more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tag system similar to the BBCode or Markdown to allow your users to do certain operation. This way, you can be sure the input will be sanitized against EVERY kind of malicious script, just use a lexer and a XSS protection when displaying user content.

EDIT: To see what i mean, you can use CKEditor as your WYSIWYG editor, in conjunction with the  [BBCode plugin](http://ckeditor.com/demo#bbcode):

Comment: Okay, this feels great. An editor posting a BBCode and also provides WYSIWYG at the same time? Hell yeah. Thanks alot. Will include it on my projects from now on! This solution is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Can you run everything through [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and just allow the minimum tags possible?

You may also want to look at [html purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) which should give you more options including control over css

What I usually do is save two copies of the WYSIWYG content:

1. the original unfiltered content
2. the filtered content

This allows me to reprocess the original content if I find that something vital has been stripped out and also show the user their original html when editing. Obviously I display the filtered content wherever it is displayed on the site.

Answer (score 0):

using Laravel you might also have to sanitize for blade template stuff. You don't want users entering in stuff like: {{{phpInfo()}}}.

Building a WYSIWYG editor requires the users to have some level of trust. If you don't trust the users at all your best option is what is mentioned earlier using custom tags.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that xss attacks are an output problem.

There is no security risk if you store

`<script>alert('Hacking your website in 3...2...')</script>`

in your database - it is just text - it doesnt mean anything.
I encourage escaping all output, regardless where it came from.
Here is a good discussion with further points on why you should filter output, not input:

[html/XSS escape on input vs output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253532/html-xss-escape-on-input-vs-output)

Answer (score -1):

i do'nt know how feasible this is for you, but one quick and easy solution is to use **httpOnly** cookies . It resolves XSS attacks via injection of malicious javascript as those cookie are not accessible to javascript.You can try to put senstive data in httpOnly cookies and not so sensitive data in normal cookie. See this : http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html

Comment: I don't care about cookies. Javascript has to be completely disabled anyway.

Comment: There are more risks than just cookies, with javascript, you can request any page virtually available on the server, perform sensitive actions on the user's behalf and even trigger more vulnerabilities, like those in the browser or CSRF