# How to prevent malicious scripting with Laravel when using WYSIWYG Editor?

Tags: laravel, wysiwyg, laravel-blade

I'm developing an app in Laravel where the user inserts some information through a WYSIWYG Editor.

What's the best way to prevent malicious scripts when printing content?

Is there any way to only allow some HTML tags?

Comment: Look into http://htmlpurifier.org/. Not only will it let you control permitted tags, but it'll clean stuff up, you can whitelist attributes, CSS styles, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I allow WYSIWYG editors and disable XSS attacks using Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17314893/how-can-i-allow-wysiwyg-editors-and-disable-xss-attacks-using-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use strip_tags(). use the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) for more info about strip_tags()