# HTML Rendering Escaped Characters

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, security, escaping

I'm currently working to solve a major permanent XSS vulnerability on my website. To do this, I am calling:

```
    this.Title = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(this.Title);
```

On the values I am taking in, which properly escapes all of the characters that need to be escaped (<, >, &, etc.). My problem arises when I go to display this title elsewhere in my page:

```
<p> @title </p>
```

Which displays the string exactly as it appears, such as "&lt ;&gt ;, etc.".

To solve this problem, I have noticed that if I call:

```
<p> @html.raw(title) </p>
```

That the values are properly displayed on the page (<, >, etc.). But I am afraid that this still ensures a vulnerability. What is the best way to properly render the html onto the page? Am I doing anything wrong? Or am I properly using html.raw()?

Comment: You should probably not be calling `Escape` at all -- just let Razor auto-encode your output. But if we assume that `Escape` should be used then yes, you are using `Raw` correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [html/XSS escape on input vs output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253532/html-xss-escape-on-input-vs-output)

Comment: As long as the output is properly HTML encoded there is no risk with &lt; &gt; etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take and store the title as is comes in. Then you escape the title on output.

See answer on e.g. [html/XSS escape on input vs output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253532/html-xss-escape-on-input-vs-output)