# How and where can XSS protection be applied in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, xss

I wonder how (if anyhow) is XSS protection provided in Laravel. I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation.

**Problem**

I am using [Eloquent's](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete) `create()` method to insert data into database (`$fillable`/`$guarded` properties are set in the models). As it turns out, I can freely put something like this in any form's text input:

```
<script>alert('Hacking Sony in 3...2...')</script>
```

and the value will be inserted in the database. Then, when `echo`ing it - the alert is shown.

**Possible solutions**

Now, Laravel is a really nice framework, so I would assume there *must* be something to prevent XSS out of the box. However, I can't find out what that is.

If I'm wrong, what is the optimal way to handle the issue?

- Do I use fancy regex validation to disallow specific characters?
- Do I use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on every `Input::get()` I use?
- Do I `strip_tags()`?

**View-level escaping is not enough**

I know I can use Blade's [triple curly brackets](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates#other-blade-control-structures) to escape strings in the views, that's not the point, though. Makes much more sense to me not to let those sneaky bastards into the database in the first place.

Anyone faced this problem already?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> Makes much more sense to me not to let those sneaky bastards into the database in the first place.

Actually - that is not true.

The reason that XSS is only handled by blade is that XSS attacks are an *output* problem. There is no security risk if you store `<script>alert('Hacking Sony in 3...2...')</script>` in your database - it is just text - it doesnt mean anything.

But in the context of HTML output - then the text has a meaning, and therefore that is where the filtering should occur.

Also - it is possible that XSS attack could be a reflected attack, where the displayed data is not coming from the database, but from another source. i.e. an uploaded file, url etc. If you fail to filter all the various input locations - you run a risk of missing something.

Laravel encourages you to escape *all* output, regardless where it came from. You should only explicitly display non-filtered data due to a specific reason - and only if you are sure the data is from a trusted source (i.e. from your own code, never from user input).

p.s. In Laravel 5 the default `{{ }}` will escape all output - which highlights the importance of this.

Edit: here is a good discussion with further points on why you should filter output, not input: [html/XSS escape on input vs output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11253532/1317935)

Comment: I agree it can be an overkill to manipulate every input before storing it. I have, however, mixed feelings about this "only output" approach. Even if `<script>...</script>` is a valid username, well, it shouldn't be. At least in terms of text inputs strings like `<script>` should be disallowed. On the other hand, `textarea`s naturally allow many various characters and here output-escaping is the only optimal way of fighting XSS. In the end, all of this remains personal choice, I guess. Thanks for sharing what you know. Very helpful.

Comment: " At least in terms of text inputs strings like <script> should be disallowed" - why? `<script>` as text means nothing. It only *means* something when you put it out as a HTML content. What happens if that text was used elsewhere, like connecting to a 3rd party application via API, JSON, CSV etc etc.

Comment: @lesssugar: You can use input validation as a second layer of defence against XSS, although the focus should definitely be on output sanitization as The Shift Exchange says. For example, you should **not** blacklist `<script>` as an invalid sequence to have as a username, but you may have a business rule that says that all usernames must be alphanumeric. In that case you should validate your input, but never as a substitute for correctly encoding on output. If your business rules later change to allow the characters `</>` you do not want your site to become suddenly vulnerable.

Comment: I strongly disagree.
You may be serving content via an API to a third party or to your own site using AJAX, it's not responsable to output unsafe data.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, the "official" Laravel position is that [XSS prevention best practice is to escape *output*](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=14540).  Thus, `{{{ }}}`.

You can *supplement* output escaping through *input* sanitation with `Input::all()`, `strip_tags()`, and `array_map()`:

```
$input = array_map('strip_tags', \Input::all());
```

Comment: One way to go. I also currently use `array_map()` to clean `Input`s. I still think `{{{ }}}` is last resort.

Comment: @bishop can you please give a example how we can use trip_tags(), and array_map(). to prevent XXS

Comment: @usama I have added an example.

Answer (score 8):

I examined the Laravel's protection `{{{...}}}` against xss attack. It just uses the `htmlentities()` function in the way like this: `htmlentities('javascript:alert("xss")', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);` This protects you against xss only if you use it properly means dont use it in certain HTML tags because it will result in XSS attack possibility. For example:

```
$a = htmlentities('javascript:alert("xss")', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false); 
echo '<a href="'.$a.'">link</a>';
```

In this case, it is vulnerable to xss.

Comment: very important alert. so whats your advise? how to prevent such XSS vulnerabilities?

Comment: @alex Proper escaping protects from breaking your layout (and executing hacker's javascript).
But there are places where switching to javascript context is legal (onclick, onerror, href) and "escaping" can't prevent it.
You must validate and sanitize data before inserting into such places.
I highly recommend read [QWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Answer (score 8):

```
class XSSProtection
{
    /**
     * The following method loops through all request input and strips out all tags from
     * the request. This to ensure that users are unable to set ANY HTML within the form
     * submissions, but also cleans up input.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param callable $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, \Closure $next)
    {
        if (!in_array(strtolower($request->method()), ['put', 'post'])) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        $input = $request->all();

        array_walk_recursive($input, function(&$input) {
            $input = strip_tags($input);
        });

        $request->merge($input);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You also filter input before validation like, First create  **/app/Common/Utility.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Common;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class Utility {
    public static function stripXSS()
    {
        $sanitized = static::cleanArray(Input::get());
        Input::merge($sanitized);
    }
    public static function cleanArray($array)
    {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $key = strip_tags($key);
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $result[$key] = static::cleanArray($value);
            } else {
                $result[$key] = trim(strip_tags($value)); // Remove trim() if you want to.
            }
       }
       return $result;
    }
}
```

And use in your controller like this

```
use App\Common\Utility;
public function store()
{
    Utility::stripXSS();
    // Remaining Codes
}
```

This code will clean your input before validation

Answer (score 3):

The package [laravelgems/blade-escape](https://github.com/laravelgems/blade-escape) extends Blade by adding different escaping strategies/directives - `@text`, `@attr`, `@css`, `@js`, `@param`

Example:

```
<style>
.userPrefix:before { content: "@css($content)"; }
</style>
<div>
    <label class="userPrefix">@text($label)</label>
    <input type="text" name="custom" value="@attr($value)"/>
</div>
<a href="/profile?u=@param($username)">Profile</a>
<button onclick="callMyFunction('@js($username)');">Validate</button>
<script>
    var username = "@js($username)";
</script>
```

Read their README.
XSS is very tricky, there are a lot contexts and approaches.

Testing page - http://laragems.com/package/blade-escape/test

Comment: package was last updated in Dec, 2016. Is it still working?